# How to increase font size of contour labels?

Tags: r, plot, contour

I am trying to increase the font size of the contour plot labels in R.
Currently, the contour plot labels are so small as to be unreadable!

Setting `cex` does not change the font size of the contour plot labels.
Which parameter should I be setting?

```
model <- function (a, b){ 
    23.86+5.525*b-2.5725*a-6.6413*b^2-5.1862*a^2 
} 

x <- seq(-1, 1, 0.1) 
y <- seq(-1, 1, 0.1)
z <- outer(x, y ,model)

png('contour.png', width = 1000, height = 1000)
par(cex=3)
contour(x, y, z)
dev.off()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the `labcex` argument to `contour` with a desired scaling factor. As `?contour` states, *`labcex` is `cex` for contour labelling*.

```
contour(x, y, z, labcex=5)
```

[image]

Comment: if this is a base r function, why doesn't it follow the cex naming conventions

Comment: @rawr: I have no idea (and I really tried to find some justification for that..). Rather it's not for the sake of [S-PLUS compatibility](http://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/s-html/helpfiles/contour.html), as S's `countour` has a `labex` arg (sic!)